# C++17: std::is_same_v fails unexpectedly

Tags: c++, constexpr

Can someone explain to me, why this code fails to compile

```
friend
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Matrix<T> &matrix) {
    os << matrix.rows();
    os << "x";
    os << matrix.cols();
    os << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.M * matrix.N; ++i) {
        float value;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, half>) {
            value = __half2float(matrix.dataOnCPU[i]);
        } else {
            value = matrix.dataOnCPU[i];
        }

        if ( (i + 1) % matrix.N == 0 ) {
            os << value;
            os << std::endl;
        } else {
            os << value << ",";
        }
    }
    return os;
}
```

with `internal error: assertion failed at: "statements.c", line 4170 in if_statement`
but this code compiles fine

```
friend
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Matrix<T> &matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.M * matrix.N; ++i) {
        float value;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, half>) {
            value = __half2float(matrix.dataOnCPU[i]);
        } else {
            value = matrix.dataOnCPU[i];
        }

        if ( (i + 1) % matrix.N == 0 ) {
            os << value;
            os << std::endl;
        } else {
            os << value << ",";
        }
    }
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Looks like an ICE - what compiler is it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo NVCC 11.0

Comment: An internal compiler error is always a compiler bug and should be reported to the vendor with a [mre]

Comment: @binaryBigInt Do you need all 4 of those top lines in the function? If you do report it to NVidia, remove everything not needed to cause the problem. Perhaps you can remove everything below the top 4 lines (except `return os;`) too? Does [this](https://godbolt.org/z/odGdj3Wf5) cause the error? Can you remove even more and still get the error?

Comment: Btw, what does `std::is_same` have to do with the error? The only diff between the two versions is the top four lines. `is_same_v` is used further down in both versions.

Comment: @binaryBigInt Is Matrix<T>::rows() and Matrix<T>::cols() functions are const functions? if not then could you please try after making them const? May be compiler error message is not cleaner in this case.

Comment: Why does this file have the extension `.c`. This wouldn't compile as C code. Why not use a file extension that's usually used with C++ such as `.cpp` or `.cxx`?

Comment: Also personally I'd prefer code like `float value = NumberTraits<T>::to_float(matrix.dataOnCPU[i]);` to the `if constexpr` in this scenario...

Comment: @fabian `statements.c` is the file inside the compiler that contains the failing assertion

Comment: @TedLyngmo Your code example does not cause a compiler error. `std::is_same` is the cause because the compiler errors tells me the line where the error occurred and it is the line with `std::is_same` in it.

Comment: I just noticed that `os << matrix.rows()` works but `os << matrix.rows() << matrix.cols()` doesn't even if I split it into two separate `<<` operations. It works if I move the four operations to the end of the function just before the `return`.

Comment: @cse Yes they are const